# Getting error "The content of element type "classes" must match "(class*,parameter*)"." while configuring testng.xml file

Tags: testng

I have created testscript in selenium by using testng and configured my testng.xml like below but I am getting such error message "The content of element type "classes" must match "(class*,parameter*)"." . If any one have the solution please let me know.Thanks.[Click here for error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f5WjN.png)

Comment: Hi, can you share the code you wrote ? Otherwise it is quite hard to understand what it is going on

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="testone">
 <test name="test">
  <classes>
   <class name="sampleProj.ToolQA1"></class>
    <methods>
     <exclude name="test1"/>
    </methods>
   
   <class name="sampleProj.ToolQA2" />
  </classes>
 </test>
</suite>

Answer (score 0):

With the popup hiding the most of the contents in the attached image its tough to understand the contents. Still a few words:

The below simple testng.xml mentions the following:

suite name= "DemoXMLfileCreation"

test name= "demoxml"

Class (to execute) = "XMLdemo" and "XMLdemo1" & both the .java files are within "ManualTestNGxml" package.

You can remove the other tags and try executing it as TestNG Suite.

```html
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >
  
<suite name="DemoXMLfileCreation" verbose="1" >
  <test name="demoxml" >
    <classes>
       <class name="ManualTestNGxml.XMLdemo" />
       <class name="ManualTestNGxml.XMLdemo1" />
    </classes>
  </test>
</suite>
```

Let me know if this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Your suite file is wrong: `methods` (and not `Methods`!) tag must be in `class` tag.

Comment: Thank for your opinion, I corrected my suite file and set methods tag in class tag. error got removed but while running, it shows org.testng.TestNGException: 
Cannot find class in classpath: sampleProj.ToolQA1

Comment: Another problem means another question. You'll find similar questions about the new problem you've just described.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">; 
<suite name="testone"> 
<test name="test"> 
<classes> 
   <class name="sampleProj.ToolQA1">
   <methods> 
   <exclude name="test1"/> 
   </methods> 
   </class> 
   <class name="sampleProj.ToolQA2" /> 
</classes> 
</test> 
</suite>
This should be the format
```